# Is there a term for this kind of tail-question where the listener wouldn't know the answer?

Tags: question-tags

Is it just a way to sound rude?

> a. "I phoned you yesterday at 11.00 p.m. and you didn't answer."
>
> b. "I was sound asleep, wasn't I?"

and

> a. "I can see you've been absent for five days."
>
> b. "I had a bad cold, didn't I?"

Comment: You mean the question tags?

Comment: These are not ordinary question tags. For one thing, they don't get intoned like questions. They're challenges by `B` to negative implications in `A`s utterance. Excuses, if you like. Certainly they're not meant to be answered, since the only one who could answer them is the speaker. And no, there's no ordinary term for them, though [politeness theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politeness_theory) may have a descriptive phrase on offer.

Comment: Question tag: A question added to a declarative sentence, usually at the end, to engage the listener, verify that something has been understood, or confirm that an action has occurred.

Comment: If you trust Wikipedia, they might be called "Rhetorical antagonistic tag questions," tagged onto a statement that reveals information that the target would not have had. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question at bottom of "Variant Forms" subsection.

Comment: Thanks, you're very kind, but I've seen too many 'comments turned answers' getting blasted by attentive bystanders to want to risk that tonight.  Anyway, I would have chosen the "antagonistic" example over the "preemptive" one.  If you choose to answer your own question, you'll get my upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the phrase you are looking for is *[rhetorical](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rhetorical) question*.  In this case, the speaker is using rhetoric in an aggressive way to chastise the listener for their perceived incompetence.

For example, I was person **b** in your first example only a couple nights ago.  My friend complained that I didn't respond when he messaged me at 2am.  Using a rhetorical question was a way to both address my displeasure at the situation, and chastise my friend for his failure to understand social norms.

Now, these examples are rude and abrasive.  You wouldn't, for example, want to use 2b if a boss or coworker called you out being absent.  However, depending on what you are trying to say, they could be just the ticket.

Answer (score 5):

That sort of "tail-question" is a Britishism. It's just a common way to phrase an answer over there - not particularly rude.  As a rule, you wouldn't encounter it in the US. (I can't speak for Canada  or Australia)

Comment: You are quite right. It is not a form used by the more erudite classes in Britain, but it has seemed to come and go over the decades of my lifetime among working-class speakers. It is a bit like the Northern Irish, 'so I did'. *I went to the football match, so I did!*

Comment: This is used to great comedic effect as a stereotype in both the original comic as well as the movie adaptation of [Asterix in Britain](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix_in_Britain), at least in the German version. "Es ist, ist es nicht?" is still burnt into my brain, despite not having watched/read it in almost 20 years.